# Overlay `onslide` across slides

Tags: beamer, overlays

At the moment, I have code as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{1}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{2}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Overlay}
  \onslide<1->{After1\\}
  \onslide<2->{After2}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Actually, the code doesn't realize what I want: I would like to display `Overlay` with `After1` just after the first slide `1`, and display `Overlay` with `After1` and `After2` after the slide `2`.

Does anyone know how to correct the code to do so?

Comment: It seems to me that you just need to replace `<1->` and `<2->` with `<2->` and `<3->`, respectively, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: That is not true, with <2-> and <3->, `Overlay` is always displayed after Slide `2`, but I want it to be shown for the 1st time after Slide `1`

Comment: OK, I see what you mean now. No idea how to do it, though!

Comment: You can use `\frametitle<2->{Overlay}` or (without a vertical rearrangement) `\frametitle{\uncover<2->{Overlay}}`. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\againframe`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{1}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}<1>[label=after]
  \onslide<1->{\frametitle{Overlay}
  After 1 }\\
  \onslide<2>{After 2}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{2}
\end{frame}
\againframe{after}
\end{document}
```

[image]